# How to urlencode (escape) strings in htaccess?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this case in htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://example.com/ [CO=ref:%{HTTP_REFERER}:example.com:0:/]
```

All I need is to escape string %{HTTP_REFERER} but after half an hour googling and reading apache docs it seems I can't solve this one :)

So, how do I escape strings in apache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want escaping behavior you will need to add this line in your Apache config file:

```
RewriteMap escape int:escape
```

Then restart the Apache server.

Further you need to modify your rewrite rule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com/ [CO=ref:${escape:%{HTTP_REFERER}}:example.com:0:/]
```

Comment: This currently not encodes `&`. So you can not use this to escape (for example) an URL with query string.